# How to send emails to Mailcatcher with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailcatcher

I have a question which might be a bit stupid, but I can not cope with my problem :
I am developing an App  where I have to send emails to the users, that's why I am using the PHPMailer library. I tested the application with Google's smtp server and the emails are delivered as expected. Now I installed mailcatcher in order to test my emails locally, but I have no idea how to do it. 
In the documentation of mailcatcher is written:
Send mail through smtp://localhost:1025
How to do this with PHPMailer? Currently I have :

```
'SMTPDebug'=> 2 ,
'Host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'Username'=>'XXXX@gmail.com',
'Password'=>'XXXXXX',
'SMTPSecure'=>'tls',
'Port'=>587,
'From'=> 'test',
'FromName'=> 'test',
'Subject'=>'test',
'IsHTML'=>true
```

What do I need to change? I tried changng the host to smtp://localhost:1025 , but messages are not delivered.
Thank you !

Comment: This does not truly answer your question, but why not use something like https://mailtrap.io/ instead?

Comment: Also - have you seen this setup guide? https://serversforhackers.com/setting-up-mailcatcher

Comment: Yes, I did ,but can not send the emails using PHPMailer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like the most likely 2 things to change

```
'SMTPDebug'=> 2 ,
//'Host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'Host' => '127.0.0.1',
'Username'=>'XXXX@gmail.com',
'Password'=>'XXXXXX',
'SMTPSecure'=>'tls',
//'Port'=>587,
'Port'=>1025,
'From'=> 'test',
'FromName'=> 'test',
'Subject'=>'test',
'IsHTML'=>true
```

You may also need to remove

```
SMTPSecure'=>'tls',
```

depending on how clever mailcather is

Answer (score 0):

Very easy set the port to **1025** and the host to localhost.

```
'SMTPDebug'=> 2 ,
'Host' => 'localhost',
'Username'=>'XXXX@gmail.com',
'Password'=>'XXXXXX',
'SMTPSecure'=>'tls',
'Port'=>1025,
'From'=> 'test',
'FromName'=> 'test',
'Subject'=>'test',
'IsHTML'=>true
```

mailcatcher listen to that port and catch all emails on that port.

> Local scripts can then connect to SMTP at localhost port 1025. 
>   Additionally, the web interface is available at port 1080 by default."

perhaps you have to disable TLS to work work with mailcatcher if the connection doesn't accept TLS.